# toArray in Scala 2.10 Milestone

Tags: scala, toarray, scala-2.10

The following Scala code works fine in Scala 2.9, but it generates compiler error in Scala 2.10 Milestone. Can anybody give me a hint how to create an ArrayTag:

```
type Lit = Array[Int]
var list = List[Lit].empty
list ::= Array(1,2,3)
list ::= Array(4,5)
val arr = list.toArray
```

Error message in Scala 2.10 is "No ArrayTag available for Lit".

Also, should I always create a new ArrayTag for new types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug, I've lodged it: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5769